# How to segregate page components into several `/pages` directories on a Next.js app

Tags: javascript, next.js

I recently started my first project with Next.js and since then my `pages` directory has grown a lot. Now I want to separate my pages and group them into modules, ending up with something like `'src/modules/*/pages/*'`.

Researching the topic I came accross `exportPathMap`, a function that I can include in my `next.config.js` file and then map custom paths to my pages, but it seems like I'd need to add a new path for every page I create, which is not ideal. I want to give to Next a single expression, something like `'src/modules/*/pages/*'`, and let it resolve the pages and routes for me (like you would do in a `ormconfig.json` file to map entities when using TypeORM).

I suppose I could group my page components directly inside `pages`, like `pages/a-module/*`, but I also have components, hooks and other logic that I'd like to segregate into modules. I could also try using Node's `fs` to iterate through my project file structure and map the the page folders, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Roman Mkrtchian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127896/12175965) mentioned, you're not supposed to do so. My suggestion is that, if you want to organize your files into modules like me, creating a file structure similar to this one:

```
src
├── modules
│    ├── foo
│    |   └── pages
|    |       ├── one
|    |       |   ├── index.jsx
|    |       |   └── styles.js <- For `styled-components`; could be a css file
|    |       └── two
|    |           ├── index.jsx
|    |           └── styles.js
|    └── bar
|        └── pages
|            └── three
|                ├── index.jsx
|                └── styles.js 
├── shared
└── ...
```

You should take another approach. As [@erich2k8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127808/12175965) said, you don't need all of the component content to be in the files inside `/pages`, you could create the same structure above, but add `/pages` directly to `src`:

```
src
├── modules
├── shared
└── pages
    ├── foo
    |   ├── one.jsx
    |   └── two.jsx
    └── bar
        └── three.jsx
```

And inside `src/pages/foo/one.jsx`, for instance, you'd import `src/modules/foo/pages/one`, like so:

```
import OneContent from '../../modules/foo/pages/one';

const One = () => <OneContent />;

export default One;
```

Yes, you'd still need to create a new file for each page you create inside `/modules`, but it spares you from a really bad time messing with Next behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could use symlinks. You would need one for each module, but not one for each nested path within the module. Your directory structure would look like:

```
├── modules
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── pages
│   │       ├── first.js
│   │       └── second.js
│   └── foo
│       └── pages
│           ├── first.js
│           └── second.js
├── pages
│   ├── _app.js
│   ├── bar -> ../modules/bar/pages
│   ├── foo -> ../modules/foo/pages
│   ├── index.js
```

Which would end up with routes:

```
/bar/first
/bar/second
/foo/first
/foo/second
```

I'm not sure what that buys you, though, really. Now your `modules` folder will have the same clutter that `pages` used to. You don't have to have all of the component content in the files in `pages`. It could be as simple as:

```
// pages/foo/first.js
import FirstContent from '../../modules/FirstContent'

export default function First() {
  return <FirstContent />
}
```

Comment: symlinks could help to a certain degreee, but I don't think I'll settle for it. After some time researching and giving it a little more thought I came to the conclusion that what I want would be a hassle and really not worth it. I'll change my approach, keeping the `pages` directory, and organizing things differently. 

I'll post a formulated answer of what I did and why, for whoever come accross this question thinking about doing things like me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not permitted by the Next.js team on purpose for reasons explained [in this post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11864#issuecomment-613291295) and in the posts referenced there.
You may read some of the discussions before deciding if you really want to hack the files structure to do it anyway.